# Spark Stuctured Streaming: StreamingQuery.awaitTermination() does not exit after writing all data to Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing a small Scala program that should get some small dataframe, write it to Scala and terminate.

I do it with Spark Structured Streaming. The data is written to Kafka (console consumer shows that everything is okay), but `StreamingQuery`, that successfully writes to Kafka, is freezing on `awaitTermination()` method.

How can I cope with it?

Here's my Scala core to reproduce the problem:

```
package part4integrations

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import common._

object IntegratingKafkaDemo {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Integrating Kafka")
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  def writeToKafka() = {
    val carsDF = spark.readStream
      .schema(carsSchema)
      .json("src/main/resources/data/cars")

    val carsKafkaDF = carsDF.selectExpr("upper(Name) as key", "Name as value")

    // kafka: writing but NOT exiting, WTF?!
    carsKafkaDF.writeStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("topic", "rockthejvm")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoints_demo")
      .start().awaitTermination()

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        writeToKafka()
  }
}
```

And here's the json `cars/cars.json`

```
{"Name":"chevrolet chevelle malibu", "Miles_per_Gallon":18, "Cylinders":8, "Displacement":307, "Horsepower":130, "Weight_in_lbs":3504, "Acceleration":12, "Year":"1970-01-01", "Origin":"USA"}
{"Name":"buick skylark 320", "Miles_per_Gallon":15, "Cylinders":8, "Displacement":350, "Horsepower":165, "Weight_in_lbs":3693, "Acceleration":11.5, "Year":"1970-01-01", "Origin":"USA"}
{"Name":"plymouth satellite", "Miles_per_Gallon":18, "Cylinders":8, "Displacement":318, "Horsepower":150, "Weight_in_lbs":3436, "Acceleration":11, "Year":"1970-01-01", "Origin":"USA"}
{"Name":"amc rebel sst", "Miles_per_Gallon":16, "Cylinders":8, "Displacement":304, "Horsepower":150, "Weight_in_lbs":3433, "Acceleration":12, "Year":"1970-01-01", "Origin":"USA"}
{"Name":"ford torino", "Miles_per_Gallon":17, "Cylinders":8, "Displacement":302, "Horsepower":140, "Weight_in_lbs":3449, "Acceleration":10.5, "Year":"1970-01-01", "Origin":"USA"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not "freezing", it is waiting [for a new batch files](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources) in that directory.

If you want to start the job, and have it end, you want to batch with `spark.read.json` and `spark.write.format("kafka")` rather than use the `read/write Stream` methods

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like it works. Especially when i finally used `.read.save()` instead of just `.read()`

Answer (score 1):

Stream is by definition infinite, that's why it didn't finish. You have two possible solutions:

- use `spark.read` and then `df.write.format("kafka")` as mentioned by @OneCricketeer, but it could be more complex if you need to handle only new files, as you will need to track somewhere which files were already processed, and which not
- use explicit trigger with `Trigger.Once` or `Trigger.AvailableNow` (in Spark 3.3) to process only new data since previous run, and finish, instead of waiting indifinitely.   See [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers) for more examples.  In your case it could be something like this:

```scala
carsKafkaDF.writeStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("topic", "rockthejvm")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoints_demo")
      .trigger(Trigger.Once())
      .start().awaitTermination()
```

Comment: And can I hope that if I'm using `Trigger.Once` Spark will process *all* new data in dataframe using just one microbatch, even if i have about 100M new entries?

Comment: yes, with Trigger.Once and Spark 3 it will do everything in one microbatch